# Unable to send data to SNS from lambda using designer vew

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

When following [Introducing AWS Lambda Destinations](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/) I'm told to create an SNS as destination, I do that:

[image: AWS lambda designer view]

But it doesn't send anything. I had already an SNS able to send mail to my account, and I have adapted the policy to accept everything from everyone (it works with the 'Publish another message' button)

If I call the sns from code it works:

```
if (event.Success) {
        console.log("Success");
        context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
        var sns = new AWS.SNS();

        sns.publish({
            Message: 'File(s) uploaded successfully',
            TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:XXX:YYY:ZZZ'
        }, (err,data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.stack);
                return;
            }
            callback(null);
        });

}
```

But I was hoping not having to write code for that (that what's suggested from the blog entry) so for example if I change the SNS topic I don't have to change the code.

Have any of you succeeded in doing this?
Thanks,

Comment: Logs don't show any errors?

Comment: @Marcin I'm afraid that they don't :(

Comment: just in case someone is facing the same issue: everything works as expected if you test it with the aws-cli, it is just the 'Test' button in the lambda UI the one not working.

Comment: `$ aws lambda invoke --function-name <your-lambda-name> --invocation-type Event --payload '{"Success":true'} response.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reviewed and replicated the [AWS Lambda Destinations blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/) successfully without modifying the sample code snippet from the blog.

I would suggest, you review your SNS configuration (and change us-west-2 region to your AWS region of use as need be) and check if it matches the following:

**1.** On your **SNS topic** (***'arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:1234567890:YourSNSTopicOnSuccess'***), navigate to the access policy and check if you have a policy similar to the following :

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:AddPermission",
        "SNS:RemovePermission",
        "SNS:DeleteTopic",
        "SNS:Subscribe",
        "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "SNS:Publish",
        "SNS:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:1234567890:YourSNSTopicOnSuccess"
    }
  ]
}
```

**2.** On your **Lambda role** ***('arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/YourLambdaDestinationRole')***, make sure of the following:

**(i)** The ***"Trust relationship"*** of your role has the following statement :

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service":"lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

**(ii)** The Lambda role has an attached policy document similar to one given below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sns:publish"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The successful published message from Amazon Lambda to SNS topic should output something similar to:

```
{"version":"1.0","timestamp":"2020-03-22T16:29:50.528Z","requestContext":{"requestId":"43d109d2-54be-4e2e-b8d8-2757e3f06f76","functionArn":"arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:1234567890:function:event-destinations:$LATEST","condition":"Success","approximateInvokeCount":1},"requestPayload":{ "Success": true },"responseContext":{"statusCode":200,"executedVersion":"$LATEST"},"responsePayload":null}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I checked everything and it was very similar

Comment: ...forgot to add that thanks to your checklist i discovered that the problem is only with the Test button and not with the aws-cli

Comment: Glad to hear your all sorted now